# PDO-Login with username or email

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I'm trying to convert below statement to PDO.But I'm confused with binding values for :username and :email.

```
<?php
//$login is either username or email
$user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '$login' OR email = '$login') AND password = '$password'");
?>
```

PDO version of above statement I tried.Here $login is either username or email.

```
<?php
//$login is either username or email
$query_usr = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE  username=:username OR email=:user_email) AND password = ':password'");
$query_usr->bindValue(':username', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_usr->bindValue(':user_email', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_usr->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_usr->execute();
$query_usr_result_row = $query_usr->fetchObject();
?>
```

Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got should work, but as a minor optimization:

```
SELECT ... WHERE :login IN (username, email) AND password=:password

$query_usr->bindValue(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_usr->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

would work as well. Since you're doing a simple `OR` comparison of the same value against two fields, the above construct allows you to use a single placeholder and compare it against the relevant fields all at once. Rather than having to bind the same value twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Should I use only :login ? I got two separate fields for username and email in the database.

Comment: they're in the `IN` list. the syntax is very versatile `WHERE value IN (field1, field2, ... fieldN)` or `WHERE field IN (value1, value2, ... valueN)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed that.my bad.Thank you again.